# XSL - why does this recurse forever?

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion

I'm trying to create something similar to a for-loop with the recursive idiom I've seen across the web. My implementation is with a parameter that tells what to print. I use the Eclipse built-in XSL transformator and I can't for the life of me see why it gives a StackOverflowException:

```
<!-- 
    Loops recursively to print something the number of times specified with 
    the max parameter. 
    The print parameter tells what to print.
-->
<xsl:template name="loop">
    <xsl:param name="count" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="max" />
    <xsl:param name="print" />
    <xsl:if test="not($count = $max)">

        <xsl:value-of select="$print" />

        <xsl:call-template name="loop">
            <xsl:with-param name="count">
                <xsl:value-of select="$count + 1" />
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="max">
                <xsl:value-of select="$max"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="print">
                <xsl:value-of select="$print" />
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Also, why does `$count < $max` give invalid Xpath expression?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed explanation and answer to both of your questions. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't for the life of me see why it
>   gives a StackOverflowException

**The check for "stop" in the code is too weak**:

```
<xsl:if test="not($count = $max)">
```

**This will always be `true()` if `$max` is less than `$count`,** if one or both of `$max` and `$count` dont have integer values, or if they are undefined.

> Also, why does $count < $max give
>   invalid Xpath expression?

**You can use**:

```
not($count >= $max)
```

and thus avoid the need to escape the `<` character.

**Finally**, another problem, not directly related to the main issue:

Never specify the (atomic) value of parameter in in the body of `<xsl:with-param>`, `<xsl:param>` or `<xsl:variable>`. This creates an RTF (Result Tree Fragment) and needs conversion to the proper atomic value every time the parameter/variable is referenced. This is inefficient, difficult to read and maintain and may lead to errors.

**Instead of**:

```
        <xsl:with-param name="count">               
            <xsl:value-of select="$count + 1" />               
        </xsl:with-param>
```

**write**:

```
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 3):

> Also, why does $count < $max give
>   invalid Xpath expression?

You should use `&lt;` instead of `<` symbol.

Comment: Thanks. It works if I use this condition and start with 0, so I assume the infinite recursion has something to do with my previous condition.